# AMS transfer time on one ticket US

Tags: transit, us-citizens, connecting-flights, amsterdam, ams

I am flying from the US to AMS to London and my flight has been delayed shortening my connection time to only an hour. this is my first ever time out of the states. Is this connection possible? I have a US passport and checked luggage, can I just transfer through without going through security again in this case? Is there anything I can do now to help make this connection possible like get the gate agent to contact someone in AMS?

edit update this is now a 45 minute connection. is this possible??

Comment: If you can, supply gate numbers. Departure is upstairs from the Arrivals and there will be no Immigration.

Comment: supply them where? I now have only 45 minutes for the connection and im worried

Comment: You should be able to transfer without going through security - your baggage should go all the way through. Worst case you miss your flight; in which case as long as you're on the same ticket, the airline should rebook you on the next available flight (or provide you with an hotel stay). You may also be eligible for compensation (see http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/)

Comment: AFAIK based on experience transiting airside in AMS, you *will* need to clear security (but not Immigration). In practice, allowing for gate closure say 20 mins before departure, you only have 25 mins to make the connection. If your itinerary is all on one ticket (one PNR) you might miss the connection but the airline will re-book you. Make your situation known to the flight crew. If you're self-connecting the chances are pretty slim IMHO

Comment: [Amsterdam Airport Schiphol arrivals](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/arrivals/?query=) and [Amsterdam Airport Schiphol departures](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/departures/)

Comment: @Traveller EU requires security check for arrivals from many countries, but not from the US. Security can happen anyway of course for one reason or another.

Comment: Are both your flights under the same PNR (Passenger Name Record), the six-numeral/digit code supplied when you purchased the flights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KLM sells connecting flights via AMS with as little as 50min connection time, so making such a connection will usually be fine.

Assuming that this is all on one flight, your luggage will be checked through automatically, you won't see it in Amsterdam. As you are going from a non-Schengen country to a non-Schengen country, you don't need to go through immigration. I've connected via Schiphol many times, and only had to go through a security checkpoint once (and that took no more than 5min).

You'll most likely be fine. And even if you do miss the connection, the airline should be able to get you to London not long after anyway.